# App crash when login through google plus ios

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, google-plus

Try to integrate google plus login.

But when I write `let gpSignin = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()`

the app crash with error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Here is my code in button action

```
  @IBAction func googleClicked(_ sender: Any)
{

    print(isConnectedToNetwork())
    if isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
        let gpSignin = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()
        gpSignin?.scopes.append("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
        gpSignin?.delegate = self
        gpSignin?.uiDelegate = self

        gpSignin?.clientID = "my client ID"
        gpSignin?.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
        gpSignin?.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true

        if (gpSignin?.hasAuthInKeychain())!{
            print("Signed In")
           // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
            gpSignin?.signIn()
            // logInToBackendServerWithAuthIdToken()
        } else{
            print("Not Signed In")
            gpSignin?.signOut()
            gpSignin?.signIn()
            //  region.show(googleLoginView())
        }

    }
    else
    {
        networkError()

    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank You

Comment: Please add more code to identify

Comment: Did you added Google json File into Project?

Comment: Yes. I add googleserviceinfo.plist file

Comment: the above code has not problem. are you sure it's from here, and not another method you use in the app? Add a Exception Breakpoint and see which line crashes.

Comment: @DeryckLucian I tried. but it will return same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit/append scopes array because it is NSArray.

Try changing it to below

```
@IBAction func googleClicked(_ sender: Any)
{

print(isConnectedToNetwork())
if isConnectedToNetwork()
{
    if let gpSignin = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance() {

    if gpSignin.scopes != nil {
                let scopes = NSMutableArray(array: gpSignin.scopes)
                scopes.add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login")
                if let convertedScopes = scopes as? [Any] {
                    gpSignin.scopes = convertedScopes
                }
            }
    gpSignin.delegate = self
    gpSignin.uiDelegate = self

    gpSignin.clientID = "my client ID"
    gpSignin.shouldFetchBasicProfile = true
    gpSignin.shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren = true

    if (gpSignin.hasAuthInKeychain())!{
        print("Signed In")
       // GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signInSilently()
        gpSignin.signIn()
        // logInToBackendServerWithAuthIdToken()
    } else{
        print("Not Signed In")
        gpSignin.signOut()
        gpSignin.signIn()
        //  region.show(googleLoginView())
    }


    }
}
else
{
    networkError()

}
}
```

Comment: My app is crash in this Line. 

GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()

Comment: have you instantiated it in AppDelegate with client ID

Comment: like 
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = ".....p4ljj.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

Comment: yes...If i written in app delegate the app crash in GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "client id "  line.